# How to access the nested object value in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.form={
                Name:"",
                fields:[
                        {
                            id:"",
                            Name:"",
                            type:"dfsd",
                            order:""
                        }
                        ]
    };
```

How to access the type value in the above object.I need to push the value into it..i could not able to do..so first i thought to retrieve once I could not do..So can i have a solution for both the operations.Push and retrieve the value .

Comment: pls try this $scope.form.fields[0].type

Comment: Its working ...but we have to do looping right..and i need to push id,name,type,order to the fields.how to push all the four at a time to the fields ?

Comment: it's not really clear what it is you are trying to do here, exactly.  are you trying to assign values from another object, or bind this to an HTML template, or something else?  can you update the question with a sample of the code you have tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code:::

```
$scope.savebutton = function() {
  angular.forEach($scope.textboxes, function(text) {

    if (text != undefined && text.length != 0) {
      inputs = [];
      angular.forEach($scope.textboxes, function(t) {
        inputs.push(t);
      });
    }
  });
  var textfield = {
    id: "1",
    Name: "textbox"
  }


  $scope.form = {};
  $scope.form.fields = [];

  $scope.form.fields.push(textfield);
  console.log(angular.toJson($scope.form));
  ngDialog.closeAll();
};
```

Comment: I am getting an error when i use that statement. Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: you are getting this error because you couldn't create  '$scope.form.fields' before 'push'

Comment: you have to create "$scope.form.fields" before pushing.